# How to get first number in element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, text

I have a HTML code as following code, I want get first number from it with `.each()` loop in jQuery and remove duplicate numbers. How is it?

```js
$('.sada').each(function() {
    num = $(this).text();
    $('.d').append('<div clas="sada">'+num+'</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d"></div>
<div class="m">
    <div class="sada">Similar, Questions : 09214239397</div>
    <div class="sada">redirect using : 09126723272 09334239397</div>
    <div class="sada">using,jQuery : 09354239397 884512545</div>
    <div class="sada">object,with : 09126723272 09334239397</div>
</div>
```

I want this result:

> 09214239397 
> 09126723272 
> 09354239397

Comment: what does the div with class s9 contain ?

Comment: @Mohammad Yes,i want get first number and remove other text and remove duplicate numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex in [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to finding target number in text. Also use [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to checking existence of element contain target number.

```js
$(".m > .sada").each(function() {
    var num = $(this).text().match(/([\d]+)/g)[0];
    if ( !$(".d > .sada").is(":contains("+num+")") )
        $(".d").append('<div class="sada">'+num+'</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d"></div>
<br>
<div class="m">
    <div class="sada">Similar, Questions : 09214239397</div>
    <div class="sada">redirect using : 09126723272 09334239397</div>
    <div class="sada">using,jQuery : 09354239397 884512545</div>
    <div class="sada">object,with : 09126723272 09334239397</div>
</div>
```

Also you can use `$('.d').append($(this).clone().text(num))` to inserting element to `.d`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the `divs` and match the numbers with `regex`.

```
var numbers = [];

$(".m .sada").each(function() {
    // match and get the first number
    var number = $(this).html().match(/(\d+)/)[0];

    // check with inArray to get unique
    if( numbers.indexOf(number) == -1 )
        numbers.push(number);
});

// numbers now contains all the first numbers as array
console.log(numbers);
```

[Working demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/6tcd5uat/1/)

---

As I'm not sure if you want to replace the content in your div's only, here is a second example replacing the content in your `.sada` divs and filtering the unique numbers.

I'll used an array for check existence.

```
var numbers = [];

$(".m .sada").each(function() {
    var element = $(this),
        number = element.html().match(/(\d+)/)[0];

    // if first occurence, keep div
    if( numbers.indexOf(number) == -1 ) {
        element.html(number);
        numbers.push(number);
    }

    // otherwise remove div
    else {
        element.remove();
    }
});
```

[Working demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/6tcd5uat/4/)

Comment: You should use `text()` instead of `html()`

Comment: @j08691, look at my example and tell me where you see double numbers? The numbers are different by one digit each.

Comment: Your solution only returns the first number from every `.sodo` div.

Comment: Ah you're right. Your example is different from the OP's code which is what I was using as a reference.

Comment: How is remove duplicate numbers.

Comment: I copied it, but he changed the values. ;) But i think i misudnerstood the question anyway. As in the other answer, he might want to replace the div's content.

Comment: @Mehdi You don't need to use array, you can use `:contains` to finding duplicate number.

Comment: @Mohammad: `:contains` is super slow, I would never use this. Better use another variable or something for your checks. In this case it might be working, but it's not great ...

Comment: @Mehdi What is meaning of slow and what is amount of slow, while count of element is 4. If count of element is 1000, it take long less than 1 milisecond that isn't computable for javascript!. See https://jsfiddle.net/e3bfg1f1/

Comment: @Mohammad:How is If the text is Arabic? as `سیبسش، یسش: 09126728272 09334239397
` ...

Comment: @Mehdi There is no feeling difference in execute time between arabic and english character.

Comment: How is for  arabic character?

Comment: @Mohammad Slow means slower than other solutions. And your script didn't run in less then 1ms. Your example didn't even used timestamps, how do you compare?! https://jsfiddle.net/e3bfg1f1/4/

Comment: @eisbehr You are right, but it is feeling in long document. In SO short answer is perceptible.

Comment: @Mehdi What is meaning of don't work? It work in snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want

```
   <div class="d"></div>
    <div class="m">
        <div class="sada">
            Similar, Questions : 09214239397
        </div>
        <div class="sada">
            redirect using : 09126723272 09334239397
        </div>
        <div class="sada">
            using,jQuery : 09354239397 884512545
        </div>
        <div class="sada">
            object,with : 09126723272 09334239397
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var numbers = [];

        $('.sada').each(function (array, callback) {
            items = $(this).text().split(" ");

            $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                item = $.trim(item);

                if ($.isNumeric(item)) {
                    if (numbers.indexOf(item) < 0) {
                        numbers.push(item);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        $.each(numbers, function (index, item) {
            $('.d').append('<div clas="sada">' + item + '</div>');
        });
    </script>
```